# Present simple tense and present continuous tense usages

Tags: grammar, present-tense, present-continuous

I'm learning these two tense but i got perplexed since they can both be using to express "something happen in the near future". I have some examples here.

- She is meeting some friends tonight.
- We are going on vacation in July.
- David is learning to drive tomorrow.
- Vicky and i are teaching English next week.

They are both Present Continuous Tense, what if i want using Present Simple Tense to expressing same thing.

- She meet some friends tonight.
- We go on vacation in July.
- David learn to drive tomorrow.
- Vicky and i teach English next week.

Is that right?

Welcome to answer or just correct this question's grammar, thanks.

Comment: Get the conjugations of the verbs correct: *She meets*, and *David learns*.

Comment: You probably wouldn't say *David learns to drive tomorrow* because it takes more than one day to learn to drive. Similarly for *teach English*, unless this is the only week you are teaching English.